# Implementing a "Search as you type" in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am trying to implement a ***search as you type*** screen in my Silverlight application. The idea is that I have a screen with a textedit control and a listbox. The listbox is filled with all my data.

When the user types something in the textbox the following happens:

- All the items that are not containing all the letters from the user input are hidden.
- The matching letters of the visible list items are highlighted with a different color.

I am not sure how to start with this, so all pointers, samples and hints are welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using a CollectionViewSource.  A CollectionViewSource has the ability to filter items.  You can bind your ListBox to the CollectionViewSource and handle Filter event to do the filtering.  Bind your "Search Box" to a Text property which you can use in your Filter event.  You can handle the "KeyUp" event of the TextBox control to kick off your filtering, by calling the Refresh method on the CollectionViewSource View.

Filtering Data using CollectionViewSource: http://xamlcoder.com/blog/2010/10/27/filtering-data-using-collectionviewsource/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.filter.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/04/updated-silverlight-3-datagrid-grouping-data-pagedcollectionview.aspx

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=392

Sudo code:

```
// ViewModel - properties should fire NotifyPropertyChanged
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModel
  {
    this.Data = new CollectionViewSource();
    this.Data.Source = this.GenerateObjects();
    this.Data.Filter += (s,e) =>
    {
      // TODO: add filter logic
      DataObject item = e.Item as DataObject;
      return item.Name.Contains(this.SearchText);
    };
  }
  public string SearchText{get;set;}
  public CollectionViewSource Data {get;set;}

  private List<DataObject> GenerateObjects(){ // generate list of data objects }
}

// View XAML
<StackPanel>
  <TextBox Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay}" KeyUp="OnKeyUp"/>

  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Data.View}"/>
</StackPanel>


// View Code Behind
public class View : UserControl
{
  public View() { this.DataContext = new ViewModel(); }

  private ViewModel ViewModel { get { return this.DataContext as ViewModel; } }

  private OnKeyUp()
  {
    this.ViewModel.Data.View.Refresh();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Joe This looks very good. Do you have any ideas how to highlight the letters on the items that are in my search string?

Comment: Yes, you can use the Highlight TextBlock by Jeff Wilcox.

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/08/sl3-highlighting-text-block/

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for your highlight textblock suggestion

Comment: What properties should fire the properties changed event in the ViewModel class?

Comment: Any property that is bound to the UI, in this case both the SearchText and Data properties.

Comment: @Joe, If I understand this correctly, the INotifyPropertyChanged is needed only to notify the UI Controls about the changes of the underlying data. Is this correct? I tried to implement your example and the {Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay} binding is not updating the searchtext in the viewmodel thus the search is always happening on empty search text. Is this problem connected to the INotifyProperty interface?

Comment: @gyurisc you're right - the binding doesn't update until you tab out of the TextBox. This isn't an issue with the interface, but with the binding.  To update the property when the text changes, you can use a behavior.  Here's a sample one:  http://zoltanarvai.wordpress.com/2009/07/22/binding-update-on-textbox-textchanged-event-using-behaviors/

Comment: In MVVM pattern user control event triggers must not access viewmodel class. Instead you can try UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged binding attribute to force each key stroke update property in view Model.

Comment: I believe the PropertyChanged UpdateSourceTrigger is available in Silverlight 5, but not previous versions.  So just be aware!

Answer (score 3):

You may want to start with the AutocompleteBox from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).

It has a number of handy points where you would be able to extend it's functionality, for example in the instance searching your pool of values.

Comment: Hi Ralph! Thanks for the hint. I will try it out. My only problem with it that I need to change this from a combobox to an edit and a listbox control. I will give it a try.

Comment: After you install the toolkit you'll get a samples app to explore.  You'll see they demo using a datagrid as just one of many options for a custom selector.